# Authentication in Azure DevOps Server using Windows Auth

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, windows-authentication

I don't understand how authenticate to Azure DevOps Server using Windows Auth.

I create a ASP.NET Web API project that identifies users using Windows Auth (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth#kestrel).

But how can I get data from Azure DevOps Server use identified user? The documentation says that you can use "Windows Auth" for authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth).

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
    // It's work and contained windows username
    // User - HttpContext.User (ClaimsPrincipal)

    // But what to do next?! How can I send a request using this user?
    // https://{azure}/{org}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
}
```

Should I take some data from the ClaimsPrincipal class and add it to my request header?

Comment: the secon link you posed talked about oauth2 not windows auth.

Comment: @Thomas , take a closer look, at the top of the article it says: Client Libraries are a series of packages built specifically for extending Azure DevOps Server functionality. For on-premises users, we recommend using Client Libraries, Windows Auth, or personal access tokens (PATs) to authenticate on behalf of a user.

Comment: Per the update below from Azure DevOps perspective, it provided the answer to the original query with a sample on how to use Windows Auth to authenticate access to Azure DevOps Server and retrieve data. It is recommended you isolate the query and followed-up requirements into different threads for further discussion. You may consider marking the answer below which may help others with similar questions in this scope. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Based on the old [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/DualSupportClientSample) of [Client Library (Interactive and **Windows authentication**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops-2022#authenticating) in the [Guide to authenication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops-2022), I have managed to update the sample, which generates interactive sign in prompts for **Azure DevOps Services** users and leverages **seemless Windows credential authentication** for **Azure DevOps Server** users.

> If you are a TFS user authentication should happen in the background.

Here is the updated code in my .NET Framework console app. [For **Azure DevOps Services users**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2022#visual-studio-sign-in-prompt-microsoft-account-or-microsoft-entra-backend-for-rest-services-net-framework-only),

> Since the .NET Core version doesn't support interactive dialogs, this sample applies only to the .NET Framework version of the clients.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TFSWindowsAuthAppClient
{
    //After running the console will close so please add a breakpoint or sleep to see output.
    public class Program
    {
        //============= Config [Edit these with your settings] =====================
        internal const string azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl = "http://aztfs2022/DefaultCollection/"; //change to the URL of your Azure DevOps or TFS account; Azure DevOps: https://dev.azure.com/organization TFS: https://*:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" 
        //==========================================================================

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //Based on collection URL will either start an interactive login session or use local Windows credential authentication
                VssClientCredentials credentials = new VssClientCredentials();
                VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl), new VssClientCredentials());

                ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
                IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = projectClient.GetProjects().Result;
                foreach (TeamProjectReference p in projects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
SDK References:

[ProjectHttpClient Class (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.core.webapi.projecthttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

[VssClientCredentials Class (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dn245453(v=vs.120))

---

Here is my example to use the authentication with the local user account (username `Alvin` and its password) on the Windows machine hosting my Azure DevOps server, which calls this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP);
I succeed in listing the project in my collection.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace TFSWindowsAuthApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {

            var baseAddress = new Uri("http://aztfs2022/DefaultCollection/");

            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("Alvin", "AzxxPasswordxx");

            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = networkCredential };

            var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?api-version=7.0").Result;

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope the sample could help.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But the ClaimsPrincipal class does not seem to contain the password explicitly. So I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: So may I assume your actual query is about how to get the credentials/password information of the Windows local user account with `ClaimsPrincipal` class or with any other method? I am not sure if this is possible to retrieve a user's password from an application when there is no authorization before it and don't you think the process will incur security issue? Besides, that part doesn't seem to be a topic about Azure DevOps authentication.

Comment: My goal is authentication on Azure DevOps Server using Windows Auth. I am able to authenticate in my application (ASP.NET Web API). I have some user data (ClaimsPrincipal). But what to do next? How to get some data from Azure DevOps Server using this user.

Perhaps you need to authenticate differently, but I don’t know how.

Comment: Hi there, I have discovered the official sample and figured out the update. Please feel welcome to test in .NET Framework console app based on the update.

Comment: I do not understand you. Your example is not suitable because it requires a login and password.

Comment: Oops, I see you updated your answer and added another example using VssClientCredentials. This example will work from the user who had the console application running. I want to make an application that will be hosted on a server and other users can access this server from their computers.

Comment: The answer is updated based on the official sample to use Windows Auth for authentication access to Azure DevOps Server. Regarding the followed up requirement that others can access Server from their PCs, it may concern other topics on how to authenticate with TFS domain accounts and how the sever url can be resolved on user computers. Please raise another thread for discussion. You may check [other auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops-2022) that may meet your requirements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77676060