# How to call an Azure DevOps API method on behalf of a user?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-devops

I am developing a ASP.NET Core Web API application. I selected the ['Windows' authentication type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).

Inside my methods I can get some information ([ClaimsPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-8.0)) about the user who called the API method. For example:

- `User.Identity.Name` - username
- `User.Identity.AuthenticationType` - auth type (= NTLM)
- and etc.

How can I make a request from my API application to another API application (Azure DevOps API) on **behalf of this user**?

Is it possible to extract a user's password from `ClaimsPrincipal`? Or how can I create a token (PAT or HTTP Negotiate) from `ClaimsPrincipal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your questions:

> How can I make a request from my API application to another API application (Azure DevOps API) on behalf of this user?

1. Ensure your Windows system has joined in a domain of an Azure AD (Microsoft Entra ID).
2. Ensure the user identity who logs in the Windows system also has been backed to the Azure AD.
3. Ensure the Azure DevOps organization has backed to the Azure AD. And the user also has been added into this organization.
4. After above preparations, then you can use below method to authenticate the Azure DevOps client API with your username and password. Also see "[**Microsoft Entra authentication for REST services**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#microsoft-entra-authentication-for-rest-services)".

   ```
   // Create instance of VssConnection using Azure AD Credentials for Azure AD backed account.
   VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssAadCredential(userName, password));
   ```

---

> Is it possible to extract a user's password from ClaimsPrincipal? Or how can I create a token (PAT or HTTP Negotiate) from ClaimsPrincipal?

I am afraid that there is no way to get the user's password (or generate the access token) using the **`ClaimsPrincipal`** Class.

You may need to generate an Azure DevOps PAT for the user via either manually creating in Azure DevOps or using the Azure DevOps API "[**Pats - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP)".

---